# MonoGame renders texture in an almost compressed looking way

Tags: textures, monogame, rendertargets

I was working on a game in MonoGame, which I have been doing for quite some time now. As I was implementing UI, I was noticing some sort of weird scanlines. Investigating further, to my surprise my whole scene was covered in it!

[image: Issue]

Notice how the texture when zoomed in has almost a JPEG squared compressed feel too it. I have no idea what is causing this.

We were using a RenderTargetTexture instead of the backbuffer, so figured I try it without, but the same happens. I checked if we were doing any weird Matrix transformations, we did not, in fact, I disabled them just to test it out. After that I thought "half pixel offset" (even though it should not really apply anymore post DX9), but also that did not solve a thing. Last but not least I thought maybe a MipMapping issue, but that would be weird since the exact same thing happens with the normal backbuffer.

**My Question:** Does anyone here recognize this "effect", and have any clue what might be causing it?

I'm basically just rendering a 1920x1080 image to a 1920x1080 backbuffer, but I can assure its not the image. When I for example draw a cursor and make it follow the mouse, the points where pixels "go missing", even the cursor texture deforms.

[image: Issue]

Might not be as clear in this picture, but notice how both the cursor and the orange curve basically "skip" a row of pixels, when I move the cursor to another location, it turns back to normal.

Comment: Another things that crossed my mind was that I was maybe drawing textures a few pixels bigger than they were, pulling it out of proportions. But that does not make sense since the cursor, which is a 32x32 texture on the filesystem and also drawn as such, simply deforms when it gets near such a place on the screen.

Comment: It looks like maybe you are doing non uniform scaling (different scaling on x and y axis) and that your are using nearest neighbor texture sampling.  I'm not sure details of monogame but if you can use bilinear texture sampling, that ought to help things.

Comment: @AlanWolfe Thanks! Not sure what I did last night, but without any scaling to the rendertarget, it did look normal after all. So I followed your lead and checked if our aspect ratio calculation for the rendertarget downscale was correct, and to my surprise, it was 2 pixels off! Meaning there was indeed a non-uniform scaling happening. After fixing that, the issue resolved itself. If you put your comment in an answer, I'll tag it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you are doing non uniform scaling (different scale on x and y axis) and using nearest neighbour texture sampling.

If you switch to using uniform scaling and/or bilinear texture sampling (or better, like bicubic) the problem should go away.